# Excel 2013: Macro Version Control Strategy

Tags: excel, version-control, tfs, vba

We are using TFS as source control system and I would like to implement the following:

We have Excel files on multiple workstations (all connected to TFS) that shall always use the latest version of a macro.

Therefore, I thought about somehow defining the macro in an external file which is under source control and can be centrally maintained and mapped to the local workspace of the workstations where the Excel files are located.

Within the VBA section of the Excel files, there should only be a link to that file so that always the latest version of the macro is used (assuming that the user made a GetLatest operation on the external file containing the macro).

Is a scenario like this technically possible? If yes, how can I define that the Excel file has to import the macro from the external file?

Comment: I believe that using the add-in approach is correct for your situation, but you may be interested in [some code to get actual files into and out of the workbook](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/vba-and-git/) so you can see diffs and changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly referring to the macro containing file as an Addin should do the job.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. Does the add-In really link to the external file containing the macro so that the macro is always up to date? So far, I thought that an add-in would just install a macro and if the source file containing the macro changes, the add-in would still use the old version of the macro.

Comment: just put the code in a workbook and store it on the network. , then each machine can open that file and call a macro to run?

Comment: All macros in the Addin will be available for all workbooks you create in Excel. You only need to update the 'central' addin after which all locations in which the addin will be loaded will be updated. That's exactly why the Addin has been invented.

Comment: Thank you. I give the Addin a try. +1 for the idea of using a central file on the network for defining the shared macros.